# Variables in jsPDF

Tags: html, jspdf

how can I use a variable in jsPDF?

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text(20, 20,  'variablehere');
```

I have tried many different capabilities like ' + variable + ', but no one worked for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like you would for any other function.

```
var variable = 'test';
doc.text(20, 20, variable);
```

There's nothing special about library functions.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, and you can also call to a function that returns a value:

```
myFunction() {
  return "Value";
}
.
.
.
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text(20, 20,  myFunction());
```

If you use Typescript you can use interpolation.

```
doc.text(20, 20,  `Time: ${this.hour} : ${this.minutes}`);
```

Comment: string interpolation IS NOT a typescript feature, it's vanilla Javascript