# Exporting HTML input values to PDF using jsPDF

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I have an HTML form with several user input fields of type checkbox, text area and radio buttons that I need to download as a PDF file with the input values given by the user. I'm using jsPDF successfully to export the HTML div to a PDF but the input fields do not have any values in the PDF result. How do I export the entire form with the input values? Here is my jsPDF javascript for exporting to PDF:

```
self.onDownload = function (divId){
     var doc = new jsPDF();
     doc.fromHTML(document.getElementById(divId), 15, 15, {
          'width': 170
     });
     doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
}
```

Comment: I can't find any documentation on a fromHTML function in the jsPDF library http://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/index.html The closest thing I could find was an addHTML function, which has been deprecated in favor of vector-based solutions, of which an example is posted here: https://cdn.rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/examples/html2pdf/showcase_supported_html.html I would consider looking at the documentation and this example instead of using an undocumented/heavily deprecated function.

Answer (score 2):

I myself have been building functionality like you have described.

With regards to the issue you are experiencing, my current understanding is that most PDF generation libraries, like jsPDF, can't read/interpret the value attributes of input fields, which is why they aren't appearing in the PDF.

One way around this is to use a DOM to Image generator, then to save the image as a PDF. While it's not the most elegant of solutions, it does work and is the best solution I have found thus far. I've been using the html2canvas library for creating the image, and jsPDF for creating the pdf.

There is a tutorial [here](http://www.freakyjolly.com/create-multipage-html-pdf-jspdf-html2canvas/), that takes you through setting up a basic html to pdf function, using html2canvas and jsPDF.

Answer (score 0):

This seem to be false, albeit being a year later.

By using

`doc.text(20, 20, document.getElementById("YourDiv/Paragraph").innerHTML);`

or

`document.getElementById("InputField").value`

I could use elements within the html file properly.

---

Leaving this here to avoid confusion in the future.
For variables as asked here:
[Variables in jsPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18796359/variables-in-jspdf)